# Loss function for GCN(semi-supervised classification)

Tags: supervised-learning

When i read ICLR 2017,"Semi-supervised classification with GCN" .
I'm confused about the loss function.

[image: image description]

Intuitively, how can i understand this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner in this.

For intuition, Z_l is the vector of representation you learnt with number of F features/multi-class. and Y_l is the same size vector of multi-class label you have already knew. What you want is to minimize the loss between Z and F.

This format of loss function is called entropy, which is a classic one.
Compared with the 1-norm or 2-norm, this format can converge faster.